# How to use Three.js OrbitControl on multiple objects

Tags: javascript, three.js

So i have the orbit control working, but i have 3 objects on the page. When it controls one, it controls them all. Also pan/zoom does not work at all with the OrthographicCamera.

I have each instance of the OrbitControls assigned its own variable, so it is not global across them all.

```
controlsObjOne = new THREE.OrbitControls(cameraObjOne);
controlsObjOne.addEventListener('change', renderObjOne);
```

I use ObjTwo, Three, etc for the other models. Everything works this way (camera, light, render, etc) except the orbit. Is it possible with this library or is there another one that i have not seen that will work with multiple objects?

Comment: The controls are per camera. You cannot do what you want with such a setup.

Comment: If it where "per camera" it would work. It appears to be more towards one "per page"

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is that by default, the OrbitControls attach the `eventListeners` for mouse/touch input to the document. One can hand over a `domElement` as a second parameter. Then all `eventListeners` will be bound to that element (for example the renderer canvas `domElement`). But that will highly limit the navigation possibilities, since the `mousemove` will only get registered when the mouse is in the canvas area.

What you want is the `mousedown` eventListeners on the renderer-canvas and the `mousemove` on the document to freely move the mouse once the mouse is pressed.

I created a modified version with a 3rd parameter to hand over your canvas element: https://gist.github.com/mrflix/8351020

Comment: That is great, but does it fix the pan/zoom issue where it doesn't work at all? I wront my own zoom code so that i at least have working.

Comment: @mrflix, your modified version worked for me - thanks!