# three.js OrbitControl alternative

Tags: javascript, three.js

So i tried to use Orbit but in the end i can not. The related post is [How to use Three.js OrbitControl on multiple objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363162/how-to-use-three-js-orbitcontrol-on-multiple-objects) and apparently you can not reuse it on multiple objects.

In the end i will have 4 3D objects on 1 page. 1 OBJ & 3 PLY objects. Is there a library or does anyone know of a way to rotate & pan each individual object? I have zooming working on an object by object basis, but could use some direction with rotating and panning.

Thanks!

EDIT:

There is also the trackball library, but i am guessing it is bound to a single object as well and can not work on multiple objects on a single page?

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the dom element, it has taken care of the issue.